# How to filter case insensitive text using jquery text.match() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, full-text-search

I am trying to make search insensitive but it will match only uppercase letter, i want search with uppercase and lowercase both .here is my code,

```
              function keyup(idd){
                  var searchTerm = $("#tags"+idd).val();
                  $("#sss"+idd+' option').each(function(){
                  if($(this).text().match(searchTerm)){ 
                      $(this).show();
                } 
                else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
           }
```

Anyone can help me please.Thanks

Comment: Do you know you're using an implicit conversion to regexp and you don't escape the special characters ? Are you sure you don't simply want `text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())` ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of match you can try some thing like this

```
if(string1.toUpperCase() == string2.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the constructor function:

```
$(this).text().match(new RegExp(searchTerm, "i"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `toLowerCase()` .

```
 if ($(this)
      .text()
      .toLowerCase()
      .match(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
      $(this)
          .show();
  } else {
      $(this)
          .hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex matcher with ignore case option

```js
    var regEx = new RegExp('abc', "i");
        console.log(regEx.test('Abc'));
        console.log(regEx.test('ABC'));
        console.log(regEx.test('AAA'));
```